# Netmiko for Linux - sending the sudo password

Tags: python, automation, apt-get

I could not figure out how to send the sudo password when using `netmiko`.

I want for example to run:

```
sudo apt-get -y install apache2
```

Linux will ask for the password so I must specify it in my python script.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler


linux = {
        'device_type': 'linux',
        'ip': '192.168.0.134',
        'username': 'u1',
        'password': 'testpass',
        'port': 229,
        'verbose':True
        }

connection = ConnectHandler(**linux)
output = connection.send_command('sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y install apache2')
print(output)
connection.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

This example worked for me (Linux Ubuntu 16):

```
params = {
    'device_type': 'linux',
    'ip': '1.2.3.4',
    'username': 'myuser',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'secret': 'mypassword',
    'port': '22'
    }

...
myssh.enable(cmd="sudo su", pattern='password')
...run some root commands...
myssh.exit_enable_mode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linux dictionary needs a secret argument. You also need to call the enable() method post connect.

Note, Netmiko is not well-suited to Linux automation relative to other tools. There are several other tools that will be better choices here.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! And also the root prompt must end in # not in $ (I've also changed the PS1 variable for that).

Comment: `enable()` method for linux `device_type` expects `"$"` as primary prompt and `"#"` as alternative prompt. The solution in the post is not suitable for generic used unless `enable()` uses a generic way to detect if it has entered into sudo mode.